# antlr4 parsing with unreferenced rule

Tags: parsing, antlr4

if i use this grammar:

```
grammar NameValue;
nameValue: (name=ID ':' value=ID)+ EOF;
//idWithSpace : ID (' ' ID)*;
ID :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;
WS  :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // Define whitespace rule, toss it out
```

and this input:

```
a:b
a : b
A  :  B
```

i get this parse:

```
(nameValue a : b a : b A : B <EOF>)
```

but if i uncomment the idWithSpace line, i get this parse:

```
line 2:1 extraneous input ' ' expecting ':'
line 2:3 extraneous input ' ' expecting ID
(nameValue a : b a   :   b A : B <EOF>)
```

why does adding the rule idWithSpace

```
idWithSpace : ID (' ' ID)*;
```

that is not referenced, cause the parse to change?

Comment: I am guessing that the problem is that space is both skipped and used in idWithSpace rule. Why do you even need that space before ID?

Answer (score 0):

This rule:

```
idWithSpace : ID (' ' ID)*;
```

due to the embedded string ' ', implicitly creates a lexer rule that matches a single space character and is placed before all other lexer rules. As a result, it effectively masked your WS rule whenever a single space character is encountered. Hence a single space can no longer be skipped and is tokenized and passed to the parser.  But there is no parser rule that allows a single space before the :, so it complains about the extra ' ' input:

```
line 2:1 extraneous input ' ' expecting ':'
```

I was bitten a lot by this kind of bugs when I first used ANTLR.